# Array Intersection - only once

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

Newbie here, so I have a problem with the array_intersect function. I am comparing two arrays with intersection but I get some results twice. For example: 2 arrays

```
$array1 = array(apple, orange, orange, apricot, melon, watermelon);
$array2 = array(apple, orange);
```

`$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);` This returns:

```
$result = array(apple, orange, orange);
```

But I want this:

```
$result = array(apple, orange);
```

I want this to return `apple` and `orange` ONCE each. Currently it returns apple, then orange, and then another orange. Am I missing something or am I simply using the wrong function.

**edit:** Based on the answers I have to clarify this. If the 2nd array is

```
$array1 = array(apple, orange, orange, apricot, melon, watermelon);
$array2 = array(apple, orange, orange);
```

I want the result to have 2 oranges, so `array_unique` wont do it.

```
$result = array(apple, orange, orange);
```

Comment: just use `array_unique` in the resultant array

Comment: @Ghost I cannot, see edit for clarification :D

Comment: i don't see the sense out of it, a while ago you want to return `apple` and `orange` once each. then you want to retain it. if that's the case then don't use it, `array_intersect_assoc` checks the indices also, so in this case it lined up, `$array1 = array(apple, orange, ..)` and `$array2 = array(apple, orange)`, indices 0, 1 and values matched it works fine too, if `orange` happens to go on the last index, it wont work since it checks the index too

Comment: Did you read the description of array_intersect_assoc()? Apparently not.

Comment: Yes it seems assoc wont work :D

Comment: Please, clarify your input data and output data.

Comment: `This returns` - what is 'this'? you have provided only two arrays.

Comment: Sorry I copied pasted $array2 and forgot to change it to result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through first array. If second array has value put it to result and remove from second array.

```
$array1 = array('apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'apricot', 'melon', 'watermelon');
$array2 = array('apple', 'orange');
$array3 = array('apple', 'orange', 'orange');

function my_intersect($array1, $array2)
    {
    // array_walk($array1, 'sort');
    // array_walk($array2, 'sort');
    return array_filter($array1, function($item)use(&$array2)
        {
        if (($key = array_search($item, $array2)) !== false)
            {
            unset($array2[$key]);
            return true;
            }
        return false;
        });
    }

var_dump(my_intersect($array1, $array2)); // 'apple', 'orange'
var_dump(my_intersect($array1, $array3)); // 'apple', 'orange', 'orange'
```

Comment: I don't understand your 3rd line in the `my_intersect` function and it also produces some kind of error.

Comment: scratch that the error was from my editor runs fine! cheers :D

Comment: Just so I know. Will this also work with more complicated arrays? i.e. Instead of `apples` and `oranges`, (single variables) to have arrays stored, `$array1=($fruits,$drinks);`

Comment: @alexandros , you need to sort internal arrays to compare it. See added comments.

Comment: hm is 'sort' a function I need to implement? :D

Comment: @alexandros, no, it's common function

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the results once, you have to filter them with array_unique(). array_intersection() only results what they have in common. And that's orange, in your case twice in $array1. The question is why are there two orange in $array1?

http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

edit: This could work:

```
$array1 = array('apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'apricot', 'melon', 'watermelon');
$array2 = array('apple', 'orange');
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
$diff = array_diff($result, $array2);
if(!empty($diff)) {
    $result = array_unique($result);
}
```

Comment: cheers! :D The reason for the 2 oranges: The first array is the offer. the second is the cart. now if it meets the offer the cart should automatically bundle to the offer, but with this you could get the offer, with one less orange, and still meet the offer.

Comment: Produces some kind of error `Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /web/com/140687550521433/main.php on line 12`

Comment: Just put array_diff() in a variable in that case.

Comment: I did and its not working as expected, question is answered though :) thx for your time and effor

Comment: I hoped your script would work so I could continue with my project :) but unfortunately when I have 2 oranges in the second array it does not work as expected, see updated question

Comment: This is not a `array_unique()`-solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

All of the earlier answers have missed your intention.  You wish to retain elements from `$array2` that are found in `$array1`.  You merely need to reverse the order function parameters.  `array_intersect()` returns values from the first parameter that are found in subsequent parameters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nNseE))

```
$array1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'apricot', 'melon', 'watermelon'];
$array2 = ['apple', 'orange', 'orange'];

var_export(
    array_intersect($array2, $array1)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'apple',
  1 => 'orange',
  2 => 'orange',
)
```

---

However, if your needles array (2nd array) has more (duplicated) values represented than your haystack array (1st array) contains, then a more manual approach is needed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ooAJK))

```
$array1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'apricot', 'melon', 'watermelon'];
$array2 = ['apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange'];

foreach ($array2 as $i => $v) {
    if (($k = array_search($v, $array1)) !== false) {  // if found a match
        unset($array1[$k]);  // remove from the first array
    } else {
        unset($array2[$i]);  // remove from the second array
    }
}
var_export($array2);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'apple',
  1 => 'orange',
  2 => 'orange',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$array1 = array('apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'apricot', 'melon', 'watermelon');
$array2 = array('apple', 'orange');
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
$result = array_unique($result);
?>
```

Comment: The second example from the asker states that this isn't a `array_unique()`-solved problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is worked for me

```
$result = array_flip( array_flip( array_intersect($array1, $array2) ) );
```

Comment: This is not suitable for the asker's second example because the double-flip will destroy duplicated values.

Answer (score -1):

May be you need something like this ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php

```
$array1 = array('apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'apricot', 'melon', 'watermelon');
$array2 = array('apple', 'orange');
$array3 = array('apple', 'orange', 'orange');


var_dump(array_intersect_assoc($array1,$array2));
var_dump(array_intersect_assoc($array1,$array3));
```

Comment: `array_intersect_assoc()` is certainly not the solution here.